# How to create new json array based on matched key values with in the array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```json
var billList= [
{
  "vendor":"2665",
  "type":"VendBill",
  "billid":"60583",
  "docNo":"",
  "date":"2021/06/06",
  "duedate":"2021/06/06",
  "discount":0,
  "taxamount":".00",
  "remamount":"151.52",
  "discavailable":"",
  "disctaken":"",
  "payment":"151.52",
  "billcom":"SGMI-11",
  "ponum":"",
  "currency":"SGD",
  "apaccount":"250",
  "bankacct":"1"
},
{
  "vendor":"2665",
  "type":"VendBill",
  "billid":"60584",
  "docNo":"",
  "date":"2021/06/06",
  "duedate":"2021/06/06",
  "discount":0,
  "taxamount":".00",
  "remamount":"53.79",
  "discavailable":"",
  "disctaken":"",
  "payment":"53.79",
  "billcom":"SGMI-12",
  "ponum":"",
  "currency":"SGD",
  "apaccount":"250",
  "bankacct":"1"
},
{
  "vendor":"2664",
  "type":"VendBill",
  "billid":"60585",
  "docNo":"",
  "date":"2021/06/06",
  "duedate":"2021/06/06",
  "discount":0,
  "taxamount":".00",
  "remamount":"153.79",
  "discavailable":"",
  "disctaken":"",
  "payment":"53.79",
  "billcom":"SGMI-12",
  "ponum":"",
  "currency":"SGD",
  "apaccount":"250",
  "bankacct":"1"
}];
```

I want a new json array like this (i.e merging the json obj based on vendor,duedate,currency

```json
[
   {
      "vendor":"2665",
      "billDetails":[
         {
            "billid":"60583",
            "payment":"151.52"
         },
         {
            "billid":"60584",
            "payment":"53.79"
         }
      ],
      "duedate":"2021/06/06",
      "currency":"SGD"
   },
   {
      "vendor":"2664",
      "billDetails":[
         {
            "billid":"60585",
            "payment":"151.52"
         }
      ],
      "duedate":"2021/06/06",
      "currency":"SGD"
   }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.reduce` and combining based on the `vendor` property:

```js
const billList = [{"vendor": "2665","type": "VendBill","billid": "60583","docNo": "","date": "2021/06/06","duedate": "2021/06/06","discount": 0,"taxamount": ".00","remamount": "151.52","discavailable": "","disctaken": "","payment": "151.52","billcom": "SGMI-11","ponum": "","currency": "SGD","apaccount": "250","bankacct": "1"}, {"vendor": "2665","type": "VendBill","billid": "60584","docNo": "","date": "2021/06/06","duedate": "2021/06/06","discount": 0,"taxamount": ".00","remamount": "53.79","discavailable": "","disctaken": "","payment": "53.79","billcom": "SGMI-12","ponum": "","currency": "SGD","apaccount": "250","bankacct": "1"}, {"vendor": "2664","type": "VendBill","billid": "60585","docNo": "","date": "2021/06/06","duedate": "2021/06/06","discount": 0,"taxamount": ".00","remamount": "153.79","discavailable": "","disctaken": "","payment": "53.79","billcom": "SGMI-12","ponum": "","currency": "SGD","apaccount": "250","bankacct": "1"}];

const out = billList.reduce((arr, obj) => {                                      // reduce the original list to a new list
  const { vendor, billid, payment, duedate, currency } = obj;                    // destructure the properties from each object
  const transaction = arr.find(t => t.vendor === vendor);                        // check to see if a transaction with the same vendor exists
  if (transaction)
    transaction.billDetails.push({ billid: billid, payment: payment });          // if a transaction exists, add this entry
  else
    arr.push({ vendor, billDetails: [{ billid, payment }], duedate, currency }); // otherwise, create a new transaction entry
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var billList= [
{
  "vendor":"2665",
  "type":"VendBill",
  "billid":"60583",
  "docNo":"",
  "date":"2021/06/06",
  "duedate":"2021/06/06",
  "discount":0,
  "taxamount":".00",
  "remamount":"151.52",
  "discavailable":"",
  "disctaken":"",
  "payment":"151.52",
  "billcom":"SGMI-11",
  "ponum":"",
  "currency":"SGD",
  "apaccount":"250",
  "bankacct":"1"
},
{
  "vendor":"2665",
  "type":"VendBill",
  "billid":"60584",
  "docNo":"",
  "date":"2021/06/06",
  "duedate":"2021/06/06",
  "discount":0,
  "taxamount":".00",
  "remamount":"53.79",
  "discavailable":"",
  "disctaken":"",
  "payment":"53.79",
  "billcom":"SGMI-12",
  "ponum":"",
  "currency":"SGD",
  "apaccount":"250",
  "bankacct":"1"
},
{
  "vendor":"2664",
  "type":"VendBill",
  "billid":"60585",
  "docNo":"",
  "date":"2021/06/06",
  "duedate":"2021/06/06",
  "discount":0,
  "taxamount":".00",
  "remamount":"153.79",
  "discavailable":"",
  "disctaken":"",
  "payment":"53.79",
  "billcom":"SGMI-12",
  "ponum":"",
  "currency":"SGD",
  "apaccount":"250",
  "bankacct":"1"
}];

const temp = billList.reduce((acc, { vendor, billid, duedate, currency, payment }) => 
  ((acc[vendor] ??= { currency, duedate, billDetails: [] } ).billDetails.push({ billid, payment }), acc)
, {})

const result = Object.entries(temp).map(([vendor, data]) => ({vendor, ...data}))

console.log(result);
```